# How to toggle between functions on button click

Tags: javascript

I have a button that I want to switch between 2 different functions when clicked. like first click would call function A, second click would call function B, Third Click would call function A etc.

for html I have something like this:

```
<input type="image"onclick="test()">
```

for javascript I have:

```
<script>
val = 1;
function test () {

    if (val = 1 ) {
    function1 ();
}
    else {
    function2 ();}
}
</script>

<script>
function function1() {
alert("1");
val = 2;}
</script>

<script>
function function2() {
alert("2");
val = 1;}
</script>
```

it only ever runs function1 Even if I set val = 2 it will run function1. any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the code your comparison operator is always assigning the value of 1.  The comparison should have a== rather than a single =.  if val == 1

Answer (score 2):

You were using the assignment operator to check the value.  Use the equality operator instead:

```
<script>
val = 1;
function test () {
    if (val == 1 ) {  // compare values using == (or maybe ===)
        function1();
        val = 2;      // use the assignment operator here
    }
    else {
        function2();
        val = 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

**Update:**

As @nnnnnn pointed out, you might want to update your toggle state inside `test()` directly.

Comment: It would also make more sense (to me, anyway) to update `val` inside `test()` rather than inside `function1()` and `function2()` - keep all the control logic in one place. (Simpler even with only those two functions, and much simpler if a `function3()`, etc., needed to be added later.) (Sorry for deleting and reposting my comment.)

Answer (score 1):

If you need only toggle button, you can try XOR style function.

```
<script>
    val = 0;
    function toggle(){
        val = val ^ 1; // XOR 0^1 => 1, 1^1 => 0
        if(val == 0){
          //do something
        }else{
          //do something else
        }
    }
</script>
```

OR in shorter way

```
<script>
    val = 0;
    function toggle(){
        val = val ^ 1; // XOR 0^1 => 1, 1^1 => 0
        val == 0 ? function1(): function2();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Got it working now. I will check out the way you're suggesting. I'm sure there's better ways to do everything I'm trying to do, have pretty much no experience with JavaScript lol. Appreciate the help everyone!

Comment: Let me ask you though, if val has a value of either 1 or 0 before toggle() is run why is val = val ^ 1; needed? Wouldn't it work the same way with out it?

Comment: Top "val" is global value which is alway 0. Then "val ^ 1" means always "0 ^ 1". Thus after toggle "val" number from 0 to 1 and assign to "val" global variable. Then your browser remember changed "val" value for next time.
After first click, global "val" is 1 and "val ^ 1" means "1 ^ 1"